# How to intercept the existing publishing window on click of the publish button in sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, publishing

To write some of our custom logic to prevent the normal publishing, need to show a pop-up and send a email to the admin user before our existing publishing window opens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask